# Unsubscribes from all publication types in a single API call

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap

Following is a sample, I've been using to get the list of un-subscribes from 2 publication types in a single API call :-

```
<RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI"
        xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
        <RetrieveRequest>
            <ClientIDs>
                <PartnerClientKey>xxxxx</PartnerClientKey>
            </ClientIDs>
            <ObjectType>ListSubscriber</ObjectType>
            <Properties>ID</Properties>
            <Properties>ListID</Properties>
            <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
            <Properties>Status</Properties>
            <Filter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
                <LeftOperand xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
                    <LeftOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                        <Property>ListID</Property>
                        <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                        <Value>xxxxxx</Value>
                    </LeftOperand>
                    <LogicalOperator>OR</LogicalOperator>
                    <RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                        <Property>ListID</Property>
                        <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                        <Value>xxxxxxx</Value>
                    </RightOperand>
                </LeftOperand>
                <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
                <RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
                    <Property>Status</Property>
                    <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
                    <Value>UNSUBSCRIBED</Value>
                </RightOperand>
            </Filter>
        </RetrieveRequest>
</RetrieveRequestMsg>
```

As we can see in the above sample code, I am using a ComplexFilterPart to retrieve the list of unsubscribes from two lists. I have 10 publication types in my account and I am just trying to find a way to get all these un-subscribes in just one API call. I did try using more nested complex filters but the code gets more complicated as the number of publication type gets on increasing.

I was wondering if there is a way possible to get the entire list of un-subscribes from all the publication types in a single API call..

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score -1):

I would write a [query activity against the unsub data view](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_unsubscribe/) to get my data sorted and loaded into a Data Extension within the application.  Next, I would create a Data Extract activity to put said data into a CSV, and create a File Transfer Activity to export it to an FTP side.  Finally, I would put them all together in Automation Studio, and start the automation via API call.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response however I have to do the similar process for 1000 business units. Do you think its a good idea to follow the steps..?